module-info.java imports can't be resolved for Gmail API
I am trying to use the java module-info file with my project.
The project uses Java15+, Maven & JavaFX.
I've added a class to handle the sending of an email with attachment through the Gmail API.
The code worked successfully in a test project that did not use modules, but I am running into an issue when trying to bring the code into my main project.
I have added "requires" fields for the new libraries, but there are some imports that will not resolve.
Namely:
com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2
com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json

I have exhausted my googling ability on this issue, perhaps I am not looking for the correct solution. I am new to using modules.
Any advice or suggestions will be welcome.
My module-info.java :
    module maven.javafx.hs_doc_gen.HS_Doc_Gen_11 {
        requires javafx.controls;
        requires javafx.fxml;
        requires javafx.swing;
    requires java.sql;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires org.apache.pdfbox;
    requires activation;
    requires mail;
    requires com.google.api.services.gmail;
    requires com.google.api.client;
    requires com.google.api.client.json.gson;
    requires com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth;
    requires org.apache.commons.codec;
    requires com.google.api.client.auth;
    requires com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth;
    
    opens maven.javafx.hs_doc_gen.HS_Doc_Gen_11 to javafx.fxml;
    opens gui to javafx.fxml;
    exports maven.javafx.hs_doc_gen.HS_Doc_Gen_11;
    exports gui;
}


My pom.xml :
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-                      v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>maven.javafx.hs_doc_gen</groupId>
    <artifactId>HS_Doc_Gen_11</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- JavaFX -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>21</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache PDF Box -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Gmail API with JavaMail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>1.34.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev20220404-2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version> 
        </dependency>
        -->

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>15</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                             <mainClass>
                                                          maven.javafx.hs_doc_gen.HS_Doc_Gen_11.App
                                                         </mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


Platform: Windows 11
IDE: Eclipse Version: 2024-03 (4.31.0) Build id: 20240307-1437
Java: JDK21
I tried adding the modules individually.
Modules I tried to add:
com.google.api.client.googleapis
com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth
com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2
com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json

I get the error  "* cannot be resolved to a module"
When trying to "clean install" with Maven, I receive errors saying that the modules are not visible and that the main package does not read it, which is understandable based on the above.

Which jar says it provides those?

It should be coming from the "com.google.apis" dependency. The .jar name that I can see is:
google-api-services-gmail-v1-rev20220404-2.0.0.jar

Actually, after some more messing around. It looks like the imports should be coming from the com.google.api.client so I'm not sure why its not pulling through for those mentioned libs

Also, if I just delete the module-info.jar file, it works fine, so there must be some missing "requires" or maybe I need to "open" or "export" something?

I needed to add requires google.api.client;
I was confused as the module-info.java already included com.google.api.client, but this didnt cover the packages I needed.
